# Parsing and Manipulating CSV contents

Tags: bash, shell

I am able to parse a simple 2 column csv effectively, but I can't use the components more than once or out of order on the same line. How might I possibly get around this?

```
#!/bin/bash

export IFS=','

while read col1 col2 
do 
   echo "${col2} to get turned into ${col1}.${col2}"
done < ./table_targetting_list.csv
```

Sample input:

```
sA,t1 
sA,t2
sB,t3
sB,t4
```

Desired output:

```
t1 to get turned into sA.t1
t2 to get turned into sA.t2
t3 to get turned into sB.t3
t4 to get turned into sb.t4
```

On MacOS when I run the code above I get this:

```
to get turned into sA.t1
to get turned into sA.t2
to get turned into sB.t3
to get turned into sb.t4
```

I've moved everything around and even tried setting intermediate variables to keep precedence acceptable.
I can get as many outputs and in any order if I echo on separate lines, but if I try to manipulate the variables into an order that reverses the columns on a single line, then the results do not come through for me. It appears that if I ask for 2 before 1, then I only get 2. If ask for 2 before 1 before 2, then I can get 1, 2. Very curious about what is causing these results.

I've even tried using awk but have achieved no better results.

```
awk -F "," '{ print $2 $1}' table_targetting_list.csv

cat schema_targetting_list.csv | awk -F "," '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

Is there an easy way to do something like this in the shell?

If not, is there perhaps another way I can achieve my ultimate goal of (row-wise in the csv) finding all instances of the second value and replacing it with the first value paired up with the second. Essentially hunting through a list of `table_names`, and then appending schema_names to them like so: `schema_names.table_names`.

I am currently angling to use

```
find . -type f -name '*.sql' -exec sed -i '' s/${2}/${1}.${2}/ {} +
```

to perform the find and replace which is why I am trying to get the results to go in a single line.

Comment: I ran your code and it already produces the "desired output". I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Right?! I wish it would work for me. Three hours of trying everything and all the docs say it should be working fine, too.
I've updated the OP with the results I get. Possibly a MacOS issue?

Comment: Your CSV file is probably in DOS format (with carriage return / linefeed line endings). Try converting it to Unix format (just linefeed).

Comment: not sure how to do that conversion (I export the files from googlesheets so the DOS ending part is interesting.) I did add another column, parse it and ignore those values and that solves it. Thank you! If you care to bump that into an answer I will be happy to accept it. :-D

Comment: There is `dos2unix` conversion utility,

Comment: You might have a program called `dos2unix`, or you could do `sed -i 's/\r//'` (at least with GNU sed) or `perl -i -pe 's/\r//'`. You could also open the file in vim and do `:set ff=unix` followed by `:x`.